# Association between two models not working

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePHP 3.0, I have (amongst others) two models that are associated:

```
<?php
    # src/Model/Table/InformationTable.php

    namespace App\Model\Table;

    class InformationTable extends AppTable
    {
        public function initialize(array $config) {
            parent::initialize($config);

            $this->belongsTo('Contractor');
            $this->belongsTo('InformationField');
        }
    }

?>
```

and

```
<?php
    # src/Model/Table/InformationFieldsTable.php

    namespace App\Model\Table;

    class InformationFieldsTable extends AppTable
    {
        public function initialize(array $config) {
            parent::initialize($config);

            $this->hasMany('Information');
        }
    }

?>
```

In the `Contractors` controller, which is related to those models, the following works fine:

```
$this->Contractors->Information
```

But when I try to access the `InformationFields` model, I get an error:

```
$this->Contractors->Information->InformationFields
```

> Table "App\Model\Table\InformationTable" is not associated with
>   "InformationFields"

I did a little testing with the `Inflector` class and the singularization and pluralization of "Information"<->"Information" and "InformationField"<->"InformationFields" works as expected.

Also, when placing a `debug()` call in both models `initialize()` methods and fetching the models through the `TableRegistry`, both `initialize()` methods are definitely called. But in the above scenario `$this->Contractors->Information->InformationFields`, only the `initialize()` method of the `InformationTable` class is run.

I am stuck at this point. **Why is the association not working correctly?**

*Edit: Here are some more test cases:*

```
$informationTable = TableRegistry::get('Information');
debug($informationTable->InformationFields);
#Error: Table "App\Model\Table\InformationTable" is not associated with "InformationFields"

$informationFieldsTable = TableRegistry::get('InformationFields');
debug($informationFieldsTable->Information);
#No Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `$this->belongsTo('InformationField');` when it should have been

`$this->belongsTo('InformationFields');` (with an s)

Comment: Thanks, that is in deed working. Strange that it works with all the other models.

Comment: @Lars Ebert, `InformationFields` needs the `s` because your table class name is `InformationFieldsTable`. For the other class you have listed here which is `InformationTable`, belongsTo should use `Information`. If the other Tables are similiar to `Information` then that is probably why they work

Comment: Actually, some other Table classes were `CustomersTable`, `ProductsTable` and so on, `InformationTable` is the only exception, as "information" already is plural.